# Where are machine-wide banned IPs stored?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ftp, iis-7.5

I set up FTP Publishing in IIS 7.5 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 (Standard) SP1 machine. I must have configured the authentication incorrectly because I was promptly banned after a few failed attempts. Now I can't log in at all. Where can I find and edit the banned IP list? It is not listed under the "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" section in either the new FTP site or the root IIS node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An ip adress restriction wouldn't lock you out after a number of failed attempts. An ip address restriction would allow you to connect or it wouldn't allow you to connect, period. Check to see if the account you're logging in with is locked out and check the account lockout policy on the server or domain.

Comment: Glad to help...